# Backbone.js - How to show data on view page?

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js (AMD) and jquery mobile. I got problem to show data on view page. Sometimes the html page not running properly. Is anything that I can do to fix my problem? Any solutions?

courseModel

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], function(_, Backbone) {

    var courseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    });
    return courseModel;
});
```

courseCollection

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'model/course/courseModel'], function(_, Backbone, courseModel) {

    var courseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: courseModel,
        url: "http://localhost:8888/impec-api/member/get_all_courses.php",
        parse: function(data) {
            return data.tbl_courses;
        }
    });
    return courseCollection;
});
```

view.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','model/course/courseCollection', 'text!modules/course/courseViewTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone, courseCollection,courseViewTemplate) {
    var CourseView = Backbone.View.extend({
        //initialize template
        template:_.template(courseViewTemplate),
        initialize: function() {
            this.$el.off();
            if (localStorage.studentId == null) {
                window.location.replace("#login");
            }
        },
        //render the content into div of view 
        render: function() {
            var that = this;
            this.collection = new courseCollection();
            this.collection.fetch({
                success: function(collection, response) {
                     that.$el.append(that.template({courses:that.collection.models}));
                     return that;
                 },
                 error: function(collection, response) {
                     alert("error");
                 }
             });
            return this;
        }
    });
    return CourseView;
});
```

html

```
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#main">Back</a>
    <h1>Course</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content" >  

    <ul data-role="listview">
        <% _.each(courses, function(course) { %> 
            <li><%= course.get('name') %></li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

output

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should enhance listview widget using `$(".selector").listview("refresh")` after looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','model/course/courseCollection', 'text!modules/course/courseViewTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone, courseCollection,courseViewTemplate) {
    var CourseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //initialize template
    template:_.template(courseViewTemplate),
    initialize: function() {
        this.$el.off();
        if (localStorage.studentId == null) {
            window.location.replace("#login");
        }
    },
    //render the content into div of view 
    render: function() {            
        var that = this;
        this.collection = new courseCollection();
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(collection, response) {
                 var container = document.createDocumentFragment();  
                 _.each(collection, function(subview) {
                   container.appendChild(subview.render().el)
                 });
                 that.$el.append(that.template(container));
            }
         });
        return this;
    }
});
return CourseView;
});
```

i dont think you need more _.each in your template.. the reflow will be much better